# buildbot: not building, instead shows a "?"

Tags: buildbot

I'm trying to use buildbot for CI purposes. I have setup a buildmaster and buildslave. And, they are both connected. (I'm attaching my master.cfg below)

I have the following problems:

a) I can see the changes committed on the Waterfall page, which means SVNPoller is working fine. However, none of the changes are getting built. I get a "?" on the buildbot page.

b) When I try to do a force build from http:// localhost:8010/builders, I get an error in the logs:
[HTTPChannel,1,10.0.0.58] ..but not authorized

```
c = BuildmasterConfig = {}

from buildbot.buildslave import BuildSlave
c['slaves'] = [BuildSlave("example-slave", "pass")]

c['slavePortnum'] = 9989

from buildbot.changes.svnpoller import SVNPoller
c['change_source'] = []
c['change_source'].append(SVNPoller(
        'file:///my/repo/path/trunk',
        pollinterval=300))

from buildbot.schedulers.basic import SingleBranchScheduler
from buildbot.schedulers.forcesched import ForceScheduler
from buildbot.changes import filter
c['schedulers'] = []
c['schedulers'].append(SingleBranchScheduler(
                            name="all",
                            change_filter=filter.ChangeFilter(branch='trunk'),
                            treeStableTimer=None,
                            builderNames=["runtests"]))
c['schedulers'].append(ForceScheduler(
                            name="force",
                            builderNames=["runtests"]))

from buildbot.process.factory import BuildFactory
from buildbot.steps.source import Git
from buildbot.steps.source import SVN
from buildbot.steps.shell import ShellCommand

from buildbot.steps import source, shell
from buildbot.process import factory

f = factory.BuildFactory()
f.addStep(source.SVN(svnurl="file:///my/repo/path/trunk/", mode="copy"))
f.addStep(shell.ShellCommand(command=["cmake", "."]))
f.addStep(shell.ShellCommand(command=["make", "all"]))

from buildbot.config import BuilderConfig

c['builders'] = []
c['builders'].append(
    BuilderConfig(name="runtests",
      slavenames=["example-slave"],
      factory=f))

c['status'] = []

from buildbot.status import html
from buildbot.status.web import authz, auth

authz_cfg=authz.Authz(
    auth=auth.BasicAuth([("userid","password")]),
    gracefulShutdown = False,
    forceBuild = 'auth', # use this to test your slave once it is set up
    forceAllBuilds = True,
    pingBuilder = False,
    stopBuild = False,
    stopAllBuilds = False,
    cancelPendingBuild = False,
)
c['status'].append(html.WebStatus(http_port=8010, authz=authz_cfg))

c['title'] = "My Project"
c['titleURL'] = "http://my/url"


c['buildbotURL'] = "http://localhost:8010/"


c['db'] = {
    'db_url' : "sqlite:///state.sqlite",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following value:

forceBuild = True

Comment: Thanks. Using this I could do force builds, but I could still not figure out the automatic builds on checkins. So, I switch to Jenkins instead. Much much easier to setup.